# Serve pre-compressed (brotli) static files (Unity webgl files) from local .NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm trying to make a web app to show unity webgl games that have files that are Brotli compressed, but I can't get it to work. The files are in a folder in the wwwroot directory. I've tried to build and serve the gamefiles uncompressed and the game works just fine then. The html file for is the standard given by Unity. The error I get is the following:

```html
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '< ' gameFile.loader.js:1 
Uncaught ReferenceError: unityFramework is not defined at HTMLScriptElement.r.onload (gameFile.loader.js:1)
```

When I look at the request initiator chain it has the following:

```html
https://localhost:5001/Game/Play/Index/5
    https://localhost:5001/builds/gameName/gameFile.loader.js
        https://localhost:5001/builds/gameName/gameFile.framework.js.br
            https://localhost:5001/User/Home/NotFound
```

But the file is there in the same folder as seen here:

[image]

I dont understand why its not finding the file.

Here's what I've tried so far, the view controller for the game(s):

```
        public IActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var webRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            // Get game from DB
            var gameFromDb = _unitOfWork.Game.GetFirstOrDefault(filter: c => c.Id == id, includeProperties: "Unity");

            // Get gamefile path
            var buildFilesUploadFolder = Path.Combine(webRootPath, gameFromDb.buildPathUrl);

            // If game dir exists..
            if (Directory.Exists(buildFilesUploadFolder))
            {
                // Get filenames in directory
                var filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(buildFilesUploadFolder);

                // Find the loader "gameFile.loader.js" (gameFile.loader.js.br if compressed)
                var loaderUrl = filesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("loader"));
                if (loaderUrl != null) loaderUrl = loaderUrl.Replace(webRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");
                ViewBag.loaderUrl = loaderUrl;

                // Find the Framework file "gameFile.framework.js" (gameFile.framework.js.br if compressed)
                var frameworkUrl = filesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("framework"));
                if (frameworkUrl != null) frameworkUrl = frameworkUrl.Replace(webRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");
                ViewBag.frameworkUrl = frameworkUrl;

                // Find the code(wasm) file "gameFile.wasm" (gameFile.wasm.br if compressed)
                var codeUrl = filesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("wasm"));
                if (codeUrl != null) codeUrl = codeUrl.Replace(webRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");
                ViewBag.codeUrl = codeUrl;

                // Find the mem file (legacy file)
                var memoryUrl = filesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("mem"));
                if (memoryUrl != null) memoryUrl = memoryUrl.Replace(webRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");
                ViewBag.memoryUrl = memoryUrl;
            }
            else return NotFound();
            
            return View(gameFromDb);
        }
```

Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env... etc)
            Lines removed for brevity...

            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // WebGL
            StaticFileOptions option = new StaticFileOptions();
            FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider = (FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)option.ContentTypeProvider ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Remove(".unityweb");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".unityweb", "application/unityweb");
            // Datafile mappings
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".data", "application/octet-stream");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".data.gz", "application/octet-stream");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".data.br", "application/octet-stream");
            // js filemappings
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".js.gz", "application/javascript");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".js.br", "application/javascript");
            //wasm file mappings
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Remove(".wasm");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".wasm", "application/wasm");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".wasm.gz", "application/wasm");
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".wasm.br", "application/wasm");

            option.ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider;
            option.OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            {
                IHeaderDictionary headers = context.Context.Response.Headers;
                string contentType = headers["Content-Type"];

                if (context.File.Name.EndsWith("js.br"))
                {
                    contentType = "application/javascript";
                    headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "br");
                }
                else if (context.File.Name.EndsWith("data.br"))
                {
                    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "br");
                }
                else if (context.File.Name.EndsWith("wasm.br"))
                {
                    contentType = "application/wasm";
                    headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "br");
                }

                headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;

            };
            app.UseStaticFiles(option);
```

The Index.cshtml for the game has the following:

```html
<script>
    var buildUrl = "builds/@Model.Name.ToLower()";
    var loaderUrl = "@ViewBag.loaderUrl";
    var config = 
    {
        dataUrl: "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("GetGameDataFile", "Play", new { id = @Model.Id, fileName = "data" }))",
        frameworkUrl: "@ViewBag.frameworkUrl",
        codeUrl: "@ViewBag.codeUrl",
        memoryUrl: "@ViewBag.memoryUrl",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "",
        productName: "@Model.Name",
        productVersion: "n/a"
    };
    
    // Continue standard unity template...
</script>
```

I've tried to host the compressed files on AWS S3 and by adding content-type and content-encoding metatags to them and then using those links directly in the html file and that works just fine as well. So I guess there's something I'm missing in my application, I'm still new in regards of web development.

Answer (score 0):

So I got mine to work with ASP.NET core using your code, except with these mime types in my program.cs:

```
provider.Mappings.Add(".unityweb", "application/octet-stream");
provider.Mappings.Add(".br", "application/brotli");
provider.Mappings.Add(".data.br", "application/brotli");
provider.Mappings.Add(".wasm.br", "application/wasm");
provider.Mappings.Add(".js.br", "application/javascript");
provider.Mappings.Add(".symbols.js.br", "application/octet-stream");
```

The 404 is probably because your application does now how to handle the file extensions properly.